# Firestore Rules - Passing value to a function from a function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, rules

I'm new to Firestore and facing some weird issue.

I'm trying to create rules to allow the user to only access the data he owns.

1. `allow read, update: if isLoggedIn() && getUserData().website == 'rBWIbXyx4bhh5UMlMx1F';`
2. `allow read, update: if isLoggedIn() && getWebsiteById('rBWIbXyx4bhh5UMlMx1F').domain == 'localhost:3000';`
3. `allow read, update: if isLoggedIn() && getWebsiteById(getUserData().website).domain == 'localhost:3000';`

Rules 1 and 2 passes. But when I combine them to make rule 3, it does not work and access is denied.

Here is the function:

```
function getWebsiteById(id) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/websites/$(id)).data;
}
```

What is wrong here? Why the function is not returning the data if I pass the value from other function?

Comment: You might not be able to pass a parameter through a function to the get() function in the rules. I haven't found any documentation or examples saying that you can.